# In LibreOffice Calc how do I choose a random cell excluding cells with specified text?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

In a LibreOffice Calc I am trying to retrieve the value from a random cell within a group of cells, some of those cells *may* contain the word "None", I don't want any of those chosen when the random cell is chosen...example:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Maybe | Time |
| Time | Time |
| Wants | Maybe |
| None | Wants |
| Of | Tell |
| My | My |
| Effort | Time |
| None | Can |
| Can | My |
| Tell | Effort |

However, the only randomization methods I've been able to figure out for myself do full randomization, example:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Maybe | None |
| Time | Time |
| Wants | Maybe |
| None | Wants |
| Of | None |
| My | My |
| Effort | Time |
| None | Can |
| Can | None |
| Tell | Effort |

Comment: I rolled back your edit since we need to be able to copy the examples to actually work with them, and we cannot copy images.

Comment: that's fine, I just couldn't make the tale appear correctly, that's why I even did the images as it would be easier to understand than a faulty table.

Comment: Yeah, not your fault: the preview looked fine, but it didn't work on posting. It's a bug that has been reported but hasn't been fixed yet: [Markdown Table Display Bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360020)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I see to do this is by filtering out "None" from the list by going to *Data > More > Standard Filter*.

Otherwise, you're looking at either array formulas or macros. For a discussion of possible solutions, see https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/function-formula-to-filter/55461.

In case you can use Google Sheets instead, there is a `FILTER()` function that can do on-the-fly filtering.

Comment: the only remaining issue I have after that is that function only sorts the "None"s out... I still need to randomize the remaining non-(visually)blank cells... counta counts all cells that contain anything even formula's outputting ""... do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I figured out a way... I used =INDIRECT("B"&RANDBETWEEN(2, SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$11<>"")))
(Input was A, sorted using formula was B & randomized output was C)
If you edit your response incorporating the two formulas into it I'll mark yours as the answer.;,;.

Comment: @DeJeL: Glad you were able to get it to work. I'll leave it up to you whether to add another answer that explains a specific step-by-step arrangement and formulas, as there are perhaps different ways that could be done. Or simply accept this one, as it seems to have helped, and you've already given a formula solution in the comment. Answered questions have the benefit of being closed out properly, making it easier for others to find the information.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to retrieve a cell from list of cells, you use `INDEX()`. If you want to get a random number, you use `RANDBETWEEN()`. And now, just combine them:

Assuming you have your "input" list in the A column, you can do a formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA($A$2:$A$11)))
```

Or, if you assign a name to the input range, the formula can be more readable:

```
=INDEX(src, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(src)))
```

Now hit F9 many times and enjoy a random word from the list.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to ignore results where input is "None".